# How to log boto3.dynamodb.conditions meaningfully

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I spend a lot of time looking at my service's logs, and seeing messages like this:

```
2017-07-26T07:33:00.182089Z PID:(18030) boto3.resources.action [INFO] Calling dynamodb:query with {'Limit': 200, 'KeyConditionExpression': <boto3.dynamodb.conditions.Equals object at 0x7ffe0a29fa20>, 'TableName':  ...
```

It'd be really nice to see something meaningful in that log message, like `Key("foo").eq("bar")` -- i.e., the name of the key, and the value, instead of `<boto3.dynamodb.conditions.Equals object at 0x7ffe0a29fa20>`, which tells me almost nothing.  Is there any easy way to get this?

Comment: do you mean by overriding the `__repr__` method ?

Comment: Not unless you modify `Boto3` source

Comment: I suggest to open an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/boto/boto3 It would be a valid suggestion.

Comment: https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1202